# Excel, Date fields, Tally and Blank Cells

Tags: sql, excel, vba, formula

I am not quite a beginner in excel, but i am unable to recall how to execute the formula.

I am trying to create a tallying system based on multiple data points within the excel sheet for multiple locations and events, including pending and missed events.

Specifically.  I have created a table to accept the tally (just need to write the correct formula).

The cells are separated by event (which is a month) and when the event occurred (date), there are multiple events and dates is there an "if" formula that I can use?

Ideally i would like to tally the dates that are completed, label the tallied pending visit, blank and missed visit.

Example:

Location XYZ: 1 visit 1, Visit 2, Visit 3, Visit 4 Visit 5, Visit 6
Visit 1 occurred on 3/17/14 (completed in black color font), visit 2 7/15/2014, Visit 3 8/22/14, visit 4 is (scheduled in color font red) for 11/17/14.

Location TYA: 1 visit 1, Visit 2, Visit 3, Visit 4 Visit 5, Visit 6
Visit 1 occurred on 1/17/14 (completed in black color font), visit 2 4/15/2014, Visit 3 7/22/14, visit 4 is (scheduled in color font red) for 10/17/14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `CountIf` and check that the date has passed or has met your other criteria.